# How big could be nothing-up-my-sleeve numbers to initialize key schedule?

Tags: key-schedule

Is it fine if algoritm will have $32$ 128-bit numbers that will be nothing-up-my-sleeve numbers to initialize key schedule?

As I know from wikipedia the Hasty Pudding Cipher was criticized for its performance on smartcards. Specifically, some comments pointed out the difficulty of keeping over 2KB of RAM for the key table. In my case we got 0,5 KB. Isn't it still to much?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the way Keccak generates round constants if you want superior low end performance and minimal code size

Comment: I'm designing my own cipher and for some reasons it looks like to implement 32 nothing-up-my-sleeve numbers to initialize key schedule is the best. But I'm not sure is it not to much of kilobytes.